# Getting error while compiling LUFA bootloader

Tags: arduino, usb, atmel, lufa

I am building the LUFA bootloader (lufa-LUFA-210130.zip file downloaded from [here](http://www.fourwalledcubicle.com/LUFA.php)). I am getting the following error when I use `make all`:

```
BootloaderPrinter.c: In function 'ParseIntelHEXByte':
BootloaderPrinter.c:301:48: error: expected expression before ')' token
    if (HEXParser.CurrAddress >= BOOT_START_ADDR)
```

I can't see any error in this line. I have changed these parameters in the make file:

```
MCU          = atmega16u2
ARCH         = AVR8
BOARD        = UNO
F_CPU        = 16000000
```

I want to configure my Arduino as a "generic text printer". For this purpose I think my first step should be to compile the LUFA bootloader in the printer directory of the LUFA sources.

Comment: This is really a programming problem more than electrical engineering, but:

Comment: `BOOT_START_ADDR` is probably a macro that is defined to be empty. A good compiler would probably tell you that – but you might be stuck with an old compiler.

Comment: These are few lines from make file. I am not understanding how to fix this issue. in these lines BOOT_START_ADDR is defined

CC_FLAGS     = -DUSE_LUFA_CONFIG_HEADER -IConfig/ -DBOOT_START_ADDR=$(BOOT_START_OFFSET)
LD_FLAGS     = -Wl,--section-start=.text=$(BOOT_START_OFFSET) $(BOOT_API_LD_FLAGS)

BOOT_START_OFFSET     = $(call CALC_ADDRESS_IN_HEX, ($(FLASH_SIZE_KB) - $(BOOT_SECTION_SIZE_KB)) * 1024 )

Comment: When you execute `BOOT_START_OFFSET` on your shell, do you get a numeric output? If not, you need to fix that. It seems very strange that it appears as process substitution in `$()`!